# Certificates generated with expo for app Ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I get the development of a native react.js application for Ios that I build with expo but the old developer did not keep the key. and by doing my build I get this error

```
You can have only three Apple Distribution Certificates generated on your Apple Developer account.
Please revoke the old ones or reuse existing from your other apps.
Please remember that Apple Distribution Certificates are not application specific!
```

but on app store connect I can not find the certificates.

someone could help me.

thank you

Comment: please post your answer if you are able to solve this problem

Comment: It happens when two apple keys has been generated.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Expo, they can handle the process.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#if-you-choose-to-build-for-ios

Comment: digging https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list